# Hide and show divs with click events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to control three different div elements with three different list elements like this such that clicking on list1 show the content of div1 and so on.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="list1">list 1</li>
    <li id="list2">list 2</li>
    <li id="list3">list 3</li>
</ul>

<div id = "div1">
    <p>Text 1 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id = "div2">
    <p>Text 2 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id = "div3">
    <p>Text 3 goes there...</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: none;
    }
```

Javascript

```
var showHide = document.querySelector("ul");
showHide.addEventListener("click", function (e){
    if (e.target.id === "list1"){
        document.getElementById("div1"). style.display="block";

    }

    if (e.target.id === "list2"){
        document.getElementById("div2"). style.display="block";
    }

    if (e.target.id === "list3"){
        document.getElementById("div3"). style.display="block";
    }
});
```

This works except that if I click on another list element it doesn't hide the previous one, all of them show together. Besides this method would almost be impossible to type if you have 100 lists and 100 divs to work on.
NB: I don't want to use jQuery or CSS target element and HTML anchor text.
Just pure Javascript.

Comment: There is no such thing as `display: hide;` it should be: `display: none;`

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract your logic into a separate function, then use the `e.target` to extract the specific `id` of the list item, then convert it to the `id` of the div you want to show.

**This way you can easily handle 10, 100 or even 1000+ `li`/`div` pairs to hide and show.**

```js
var showHide = document.querySelector("ul");
var divElements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

function showHideElement(element) {
  var itemId = element.id || "";
  var divId = itemId.replace("list", "div");
  
  divElements.forEach(function (element) { element.style.display = "none"; });
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "block";
}

showHide.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showHideElement(e.target);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="list1">list 1</li>
  <li id="list2">list 2</li>
  <li id="list3">list 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="div1">
  <p>Text 1 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <p>Text 2 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id="div3">
  <p>Text 3 goes there...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exact answer related to the question and Rick OP also wants to hide the previously displayed divisions

Comment: Thanks @Javascript_Lover, I corrected my sample, any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, see coments for explanation:

```js
var showHide = document.querySelector("ul");
showHide.addEventListener("click", function (e){
    // Get all divs and hide everything
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    // Iterate over the collection
    for(let div of divs){
        div.style.display="none"; // Set display to none
    }
    if (e.target.id === "list1"){
      document.getElementById("div1"). style.display="block";
    }

    if (e.target.id === "list2"){
        document.getElementById("div2"). style.display="block";
    }

    if (e.target.id === "list3"){
        document.getElementById("div3"). style.display="block";
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="list1">list 1</li>
    <li id="list2">list 2</li>
    <li id="list3">list 3</li>
</ul>

<div id = "div1">
    <p>Text 1 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id = "div2">
    <p>Text 2 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id = "div3">
    <p>Text 3 goes there...</p>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**
Is not a very good idea to get all divs, is **too generic**, if you add any other div in your code they will be added to your collection.
Better, add a descriptive class to your divs:

```
<div class="myCoolClass" id="div1">...</div>  
<div class="myCoolClass" id="div2">...</div>  
<div class="myCoolClass" id="div3">...</div>    

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.myCoolClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

Working code using pure javascript without any jQuery:

```js
var showHide = document.querySelector("ul");
showHide.addEventListener("click", function (e){

    const active = document.querySelector(".active");
    if(active)
    {
      active.style.display="none";
      active.className="";
    }
    if(e.target.id)
    {
      const list_id = e.target.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
      document.getElementById("div"+list_id).style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("div"+list_id).className="active";
    }
    
});
```

```css
div{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="list1">list 1</li>
    <li id="list2">list 2</li>
    <li id="list3">list 3</li>
</ul>

<div id = "div1">
    <p>Text 1 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id = "div2">
    <p>Text 2 goes there...</p>
</div>

<div id = "div3">
    <p>Text 3 goes there...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can add Target div id in data of li items like.

```
<ul>
    <li id="list1" data-target-id="div1">list 1</li>
    <li id="list2" data-target-id="div2">list 2</li>
    <li id="list3" data-target-id="div3">list 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now we are hiding all divs bydefault by

```
div {
      display: none;
   }
```

When someone clicks on li, then using querySelectorAll hide all divs.
Then get tergetId from data attribute of the li and show that target div.

```
var showHide = document.querySelector("ul");
    showHide.addEventListener("click", function (e){
        document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(element) {
            element.style.display = "none";
        });

        var data = e.target.dataset;
        if(data){
            document.getElementById(data.targetId).style.display = "block";
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.